# Completion of a ring is complete

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, formal-completions

Take $A$ to be any ring, and $I \subset A$ an ideal. I'd like to prove that $\hat{A}$ is complete with respect to $I$. I think this is true since it comes with universal property of inverse limit. So I take the two inverse system $(\hat{A},f_{n,m})$ where $f_{n,m}$ are the map of the inverse system of $\hat{A}$ and $(\hat{\hat{A}},\pi_j)$ where the $\pi_j : \hat{\hat{A}} \to \hat{A}/I^n$ are just the projection on one factor.

On the other hand the diagram of inverse limit [here (general definition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) can be inverted, i.e swapping $pi_j$ and $f_{n,m}$ in order to create an inverse of the map from $ \hat{A} \to \hat{\hat{A}}$. It this true?

What's not clear to me is the following, I made an abuse of notation in writing $\pi_j : \hat{\hat{A}} \to \hat{A}/I^n$ since $I^n$ is an ideal of $A$ not an ideal of $\hat{A}$ hence I'm not allowed to do it, it certanly is if $A$ is noetherian local but this seems to much to me. Is this true understanding $I^n$ as the extension of $I^n$ in $\hat{A}$? i.e taking the completion with respect to $(u(I^n)) \subset \hat{A}$, where $u: A \to \hat{A}?$

Edit: Also (But I think is not needed) in the Noetherian case we have that $(u(I^n)) = I^n \hat{A} = \hat{I^n}$

Comment: You need $I$ to be finitely generated for this result to be true

Comment: @AlexMathers finitely generated in order to prove the edit or the statement? And why so if for the statement? Also I'm working with $A$ noetherian so the condition is satisfied.

Comment: for the statement. Okay if $A$ is Noetherian everything is ok then of course. Your first words were "Take $A$ to be any ring"

Comment: @AlexMathers Yes of course, thanks. Am I correct that the statement with $A$ noetherian is equivalent of complete with respect to $(u(I^n))$, besides $\hat{I^n} = I^n \hat{A}?$

Comment: for an example of a ring with an $\mathfrak{a}$-adic completion which is not $\mathfrak{a}$-adically complete, see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05JA) or Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Ch. III, Exercise 2.12, p. 235.